Kubernetes 502 Bad Gateway error: connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream
First of all I'm new to Nginx, Docker and Kubernetes so I may made an obvious mistake but after a complete week of searching and trying stuffs, I'm facing the same error. Also, I've seen other similar questions exists but unfortunately the provided solutions does not fix my problem.
When I access my URL, I get a 502 Bad Gateway (nginx) message and when I log my nginx container from my pod, it returns this:
[error] 7#7: *102 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: <ip_address>, server: _, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:9000/", host: <host_name>

My project uses Next JS 14. I'm running 3 pods and each pod has two containers: my-project-nextjs and my-project-nginx (the default container).
For the Docker part, I've tried different configurations. My application is in a monorepo using turbo so I follow this documentation to create my Dockerfile:
FROM node:20.9.0-alpine AS base

FROM base AS builder
RUN apk update
RUN apk add --no-cache libc6-compat

WORKDIR /app

RUN yarn global add turbo
COPY . .

RUN turbo prune @monorepo/my-project --docker

FROM base AS installer
RUN apk update
RUN apk add --no-cache libc6-compat
WORKDIR /app

COPY --from=builder /app/out/json/ .
RUN yarn install

COPY --from=builder /app/out/full/ .
COPY --from=builder /app/tsconfig.json ./tsconfig.json
RUN yarn turbo run build --filter=@monorepo/my-project

FROM base AS runner
WORKDIR /app

ENV NODE_ENV production

RUN addgroup --system --gid 1001 nodejs
RUN adduser --system --uid 1001 nextjs
USER nextjs

COPY --from=installer --chown=nextjs:nodejs /app/apps/my-project/.next/standalone ./
COPY --from=installer --chown=nextjs:nodejs /app/apps/my-project/.next/static ./apps/my-project/.next/static
COPY --from=installer --chown=nextjs:nodejs /app/apps/my-project/public ./apps/my-project/public

EXPOSE 9000

ENV PORT 9000

CMD node apps/my-project/server.js

For the Dockerfile of nginx, I have tried debian:strech-line and nginx:stable-alpine: the result is the same, error 502. Here is the debian version:
FROM debian:stretch-slim

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND="noninteractive" \
    TERM="xterm"
RUN echo "deb http://archive.debian.org/debian stretch main contrib non-free" > /etc/apt/sources.list
RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y &&\
    apt-get install -y nginx-light

RUN echo "Acquire::http {No-Cache=True;};" > /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/no-cache &&\
    apt-get -q update && \
    apt-get -qy dist-upgrade && \
    apt-get install -qy \
      nginx-light \
      nano \
    && \
    apt-get -y autoremove && \
    apt-get -y clean && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

COPY .docker/nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

RUN rm -v /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default

ADD .docker/nginx/sites-enabled /etc/nginx/sites-enabled
ADD .docker/nginx/conf.d /etc/nginx/conf.d

COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app

CMD ["nginx"]

My application configuration is, I suppose, really basic:
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name _;

    root /app/apps/my-project/.next;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:9000;
    }

    location /nginx-health {
        access_log off;
        return 200 "OK\n";
    }
}

When I check my pods status, they are all running. My container my-project-nextjs return this log:
  ▲ Next.js 14.2.3
  - Local:        http://<pod_name>:9000
  - Network:      http://<ip_address>:9000

 ✓ Starting...
 ✓ Ready in 161ms

So I suppose my Next JS Docker image is correct.
My container my-project-nginx returns this log (after I tried to reach my website from its URL):
[error] 7#7: *102 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: <ip_address>, server: _, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:9000/", host: <host_name>

From other solutions on SO, I thought the problem comes from the PORT or the proxy_pass. The PORT looks good to me so I don't know what I could tried. For the proxy_pass, I've tried to replace my current value (proxy_pass http://localhost:9000;) with http://127.0.0.1:9000, http://0.0.0.0:9000 or create an upstream (but if I'm right, it's when the containers are not in the same pod).
Do you have any ideas why I get a 502 error message?
EDIT and SOLUTION:
Here is my deployment code:
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: my-project-deployment
  labels:
    app: my-project
  namespace: beta
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      name: my-project
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        name: my-project
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: my-project-nginx
          image: <my_image>
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          ports:
          - containerPort: 80
          env:
          - name: PORT
            value: "80"
          resources:
              limits:
                memory: 768Mi
              requests:
                memory: 256Mi
          readinessProbe:
            tcpSocket:
              port: 80 
            initialDelaySeconds: 5
            periodSeconds: 10
          livenessProbe:
            tcpSocket:
              port: 80
            initialDelaySeconds: 15
            periodSeconds: 20
            successThreshold: 1
            failureThreshold: 3
        - name: my-project-nextjs
          image: <my_image>
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          ports:
          - containerPort: 9000
          env:
          - name: PORT
            value: "9000"
          - name: DD_AGENT_HOST
            valueFrom:
              fieldRef:
                fieldPath: status.hostIP
          - name: DD_SERVICE_NAME
            value: "my-project-beta"
          resources:
              limits:
                memory: 1Gi
              requests:
                memory: 512Mi
          readinessProbe:
            tcpSocket:
              port: 9000
            initialDelaySeconds: 5
            periodSeconds: 10
          livenessProbe:
            tcpSocket:
              port: 9000
            initialDelaySeconds: 15
            periodSeconds: 20
            successThreshold: 1
            failureThreshold: 3
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      imagePullSecrets:
      - name: <name>

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-project
  namespace: beta
  labels:
    name: my-project
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
    - name: nginx-container
      port: 80
      targetPort: 80 
    - name: nextjs-container
      port: 9000
      targetPort: 9000
  selector:
    name: my-project

I manage to make the thing works by opening the port 9000. I've changed the proxy_pass to my service name my-project and add this part to fix my problem:
- name: nextjs-container
      port: 9000
      targetPort: 9000


You need to connect to <pod_name>:9000, not localhost:9000

@KevinKopf Thank you for your answer. I’ve tried to set to my-project:9000 but the pod has now a Status of "CrashLoopBackOff" and the log is: nginx: [emerg] host not found in upstream my-project in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/my-project.conf:79 (which is proxy_pass http://my-project:9000;).
I don't know if it's the right approach because my pod name is dynamic (my-project-54546f8d5c-2bvnh for example).

Too many unknown variables in your case. How are you deploying the project? What does the deployment config look like? Wouldn't it make more sense to use an ingress controller?

Sorry for the lack of information, I didn’t know what to share at first. I’ve added my deployment configuration. I also manage to fix my problem (I have added the solution in my post), thanks to you and @RahulK . Thank you for your help and your time :) If you think I still need to add information which can help other people, please tell me and I’ll update my post.

In the configuration Instead of localhost, use the Kubernetes service name that exposes the my-project-nextjs container. Update it as below
 location / {
        proxy_pass http://<service_name>:9000;
    }

The service should be something as below
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-project-nextjs-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: my-project-nextjs
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 9000
      targetPort: 9000

Also make sure that there is a Kubernetes Service that exposes the my-project-nextjs container.
And check with the below command, whether Kubernetes service is reachable from the my-project-nginx container
kubectl exec -it <nginx-pod-name> -- curl http://<service_name>:9000


Thank you, it works with the service_name! I also had to open my port 9000 in my Service.
